Selección aleatoria de muestras mediante bootstrap en R
Tengo un dataframe con las siguientes características:

N de la muestra: 4800
Grupos: 5
Variables cuantitativas: 11
Variable identificadora de muestra

Necesito hacer una selección aleatoria de 100 muestras para cada grupo, mediante bootstrap. Pero no consigo aclararme con el código en R para ello. Necesito un poco de guía.
Gracias.


La etiqueta [bootstrap] hace referencia a un framework web para diseños adaptables (responsive), no al bootstraping. 2. Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].


No he probado nada. Lo habría reproducido si fuera así. Pero no consigo aclararme con los ejemplos que veo para reproducirlo.

¡Hola @Alberto Peñalver!
Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer es coger (múltiples veces) 5 grupos formados por muestras aleatorias dentro de una base de datos con 4800 filas. ¿Existe la posibilidad de repetición a la hora de seleccionar los elementos?
Una posibilidad es la siguiente:
# Número de grupos
  n.gr <- 5
# Número de muestras
  n.m <- 100
# Número de elementos por muestra y grupo
  n <- 100
# Tamaño de la base de datos
  tam <- 4800

# Generar una matriz en la que guardar la información de las filas seleccionads  
  A <- matrix(0, nrow = n.gr*n.m, ncol = n)
# Definir una semilla para poder reproducir los resultados (opcional)
  set.seed(12345)

# Completar la matriz con los casos seleccionados
  for (i in 1:nrow(A)){
    A[i,] <- sample(1:tam, n, replace = T)
  }    

A tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

Si no quieres que se elijan muestras repetidas para un mismo conjunto, reemplaza el replace = T por replace = F en el código anterior
Si partes de una base de datos llamada df para coger los casos seleccionados basta llamar a bd[A[i,],].


Hola, @R18. Gracias por responder. Al final lo solucioné de la siguiente manera: segmenté mi dataframe a partir de la variable de agrupación, obteniendo un subdataframe para cada grupo; a partir de aquí hice una selección aleatoria de los 100 pacientes con  sample_n(df, 100, replace = TRUE); y recuperé para cada selección los valores correspondientes de cada variable cuantitativa. Todo esto lo metí en un for() porque necesitaba repetir este proceso 1000 veces. Con esto pude obtener lo que quería. Gracias.
